# How i can call oracle function with out parameter with PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I'm trying to authenticate users using an function that return true or false. That function it also returns the Name of the authenticate user, if credentials are right, through an "OUT" parameter;

I'm using php 5.5, codeigniter framework and the oci8 extension for oracle.

My functions is that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AUTENTICAR_UTILIZADOR(USER__USERS.USERNAME%TYPE,PASS_ USERS.PASS%TYPE,NAME OUT USERS.NAME%TYPE )
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT USERNAME INTO NAME FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME=USER_ AND PASS=PASS_;
  RETURN TRUE;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND  THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

My question is how i can call that function, retrieve the returned value and out parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

For Procedure:

```
//  Before running the PHP program, create a stored procedure in
//  SQL*Plus or SQL Developer:
//
//  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc(p1 IN NUMBER, p2 OUT NUMBER) AS
//  BEGIN
//      p2 := p1 * 2;
//  END;

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$p1 = 8;

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'begin myproc(:p1, :p2); end;');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p1', $p1);

// The second procedure parameter is an OUT bind. The default type
// will be a string type so binding a length 40 means that at most 40
// digits will be returned.
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p2', $p2, 40);

oci_execute($stid);

print "$p2\n";   // prints 16

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

For Function:

```
<?php

//  Before running the PHP program, create a stored function in
//  SQL*Plus or SQL Developer:
//
//  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(p IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
//  BEGIN
//      RETURN p * 3;
//  END;

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$p = 8;

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'begin :r := myfunc(:p); end;');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p', $p);

// The return value is an OUT bind. The default type will be a string
// type so binding a length 40 means that at most 40 digits will be
// returned.
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':r', $r, 40);

oci_execute($stid);

print "$r\n";   // prints 24

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. Your example is with PROCEDURE but later, when i have some time, i will try that with my function and i give you feedback.

Comment: added example also for function

Comment: Isn't it possible to get a return value as a float or so?
I don't want to work on numbers represented by strings, but I have problems dealing with it.
On the other hand floats are not precise, but It seems that for example in case of Oracle NUMBER array parameters, strings can not be passed - only floats.